# R circular array/vector

Tags: r, queue, circular-buffer

Does a R package exist which implements a circular array or vector in the sense of FIFO?

Say we have this array:

```
2 4 7 1
```

When inserting a new observation(say 3) at position 1, I want the n-th element to be replaced with the n-1st element:

```
3 2 4 7
```

Comment: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rstackdeque/index.html

Comment: `c(new, tail(x, -1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `c()` and cut off the length of the result.

```
x <- c(2, 4, 7, 1)
c(3, x)[1:length(x)]
# [1] 3 2 4 7
```

This method does not make any copies of `x`

```
tracemem(x)
# [1] "<0x3cb5998>"
c(3, x)[1:length(x)]
# [1] 3 2 4 7
untracemem(x)
```

The source code for `append()` looks like it might have some useful methods to try out as well.

```
append
# function (x, values, after = length(x)) 
# {
#     lengx <- length(x)
#     if (!after) 
#         c(values, x)
#     else if (after >= lengx) 
#         c(x, values)
#     else c(x[1L:after], values, x[(after + 1L):lengx])
# }
# <bytecode: 0x31ac490>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: That came to my mind also, but I'm wondering if this is efficient for very large arrays which are updated at hight frequencies?!

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be. These are all primitive functions

Comment: Isn't the array copied for each insertion?

Comment: @Juergen - Not from what I see from `tracemem()` (see edited post).

Answer (score 2):

Well, [Richard Scriven's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven) solution is most likely the way to go but if you're in an adventurous mood you can try [Rexamine/DataStructures](https://github.com/Rexamine/DataStructures):

```
> devtools::install_github("Rexamine/DataStructures")
> library(DataStructures)
> q <- queue_create()
> queue_empty(q)
[1] TRUE
> for (i in c(1, 7, 4, 2)) { queue_push(q, i) }
> queue_empty(q)
[1] FALSE
> queue_pop(q)
[1] 1
> format(q)
[1] "7" "4" "2"
> queue_push(q, 3)
```

Hard to say if it stable enough to be used in practice though and it seems to be only marginally faster than a simple concatenation.